# Linux cd .. command

Tags: unix

Say if I need to do this a lot:

```
cd ../../../../foo/sub1/bar/dest/
cd ../../../../foo2/sub1/bar/dest/
cd ../../../../foo3/sub1/bar/dest/
cd ../../../../foo/sub1/bar/dest/
```

Is there any faster way to not always typing `../../../../` so many times? Any creative ideas?

Comment: why not just execute `cd ../../../..` and be done with it?

Comment: You may enjoy `pushd` and `popd` or even `cd -`.

Comment: If you're going that far back it might make sense to just cd /actual/path/you/want depending on how deep the folders go.

Comment: This is a lot more effort than it's worth. If you're moving between directories, full path specification or just using `cd -` (*to go to last directory*) is easier. I typically `alias h="history|grep"` so that I can use the history entry shortcuts instead. Something like `h foo3`, followed by `!450` to repeat that command.

Comment: Open another terminal window and don't type cd ../../../.. at all

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The classic way of doing this is setting the `CDPATH` variable. In your case it could be set to `.:../../../../` or `.:/path/to/the/parent/of/foo` to achieve the desired effect. You can then simply do `cd foo/sub1/bar/dest` and get to where you want.

The advantage of this is that tab completion for `cd` also looks at `$CDPATH` and will magically work.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump#name) which automatically learn from previous cd command and you only need to specify unique string from full path next time. ex.
    `j foo`,
    `j foo1`,
    `j foo2`

Answer (score 7):

You can create shortcuts for these commands by adding aliases into the bash configuration file (~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc)

```
alias cdd="cd ../../../../"
```

Then when you type `cdd` it will execute that command.

Comment: Yes, or `function cdd () { cd ../../../../$1/bar/dest ; }`, so then you can just type e.g. `cdd foo`, `cdd foo2`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across https://github.com/rupa/z, which lets you jump to a recently used directory by regex. So you could do something like:

```
z foo3.*dest
```

instead of:

```
cd ../../../../foo3/sub1/bar/dest/
```

(as long as you have visited that directory before, and nothing more recent / frequently used matches that regex)